# any firefox addon that will do regex search on a web page?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, regex

I've tried http://www.oxymoronical.com/web/firefox/FindBarRX, but it doesn't have support for FF 3.6.7. Looking for an extension that is os-independent

Answer (score 1):

You can try the oxymoronical addon by doing the following -

```
1. download the xpi 
2. change the extension to zip
3. extract the install.rdf
4. change em:maxVersion value to 4.0.*
5. replace the install.rdf in the zip with the one you just edited.
6. change the extension of the download back to xpi
7. open in firefox.
```

Comment: Or you could just use Nightly Tester Tools ( https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6543/ ) to override the version check.